# Disable debug file generation with clang

Tags: c++, android-ndk, linker, clang, llvm-clang

I am using android ndk version 18b to compile a c++ project for Android on Windows 10.

I am wondering if there is a way to disable generating the debug symbols when linking, in an effort to speed up link times.

Since I do not have a graphical debugger, the frequency of when I fire up gdb command line is seldom, so I would prefer to have faster link times.

I do require asserts to be on though, so I definitely need debug.

Comment: What if you add `-gline-tables-only` to your compiler flags for debug builds?

Comment: Does your compiler have a *release* mode?  Usually, release mode does not have symbols whereas debug mode has symbols.

Comment: I require asserts to be on, so I can not use release mode.

Comment: -gline-tables-only did not have an appreciable effect.

Comment: Add `-UNDEBUG` to your release cflags to turn assers on in release mode.